# How can I import code coverage in Pycharm executed on a different machine?

Tags: pycharm, coverage.py

I posted this already in the [PyCharm forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007755659-How-can-I-import-code-coverage-in-Pycharm-executed-on-a-different-machine-) but didn't get any response after a few days. So I figured I'd ask it here.

My goal is to import `coverage.py` results that run in a non PyCharm process into PyCharm in order to use all of the coverage editor features that come with PyCharm.

I'm using PyCharm Professional Edition so I do have access to the coverage feature.

I have python code that cannot be run directly in PyCharm since it needs to be run from within a database server  process (`PL/Python` in Postgres if anyone is curious).

I'm using the coverage package within the database process to produce a json report but I can also export the format in any way that `coverage.py` supports.

According to Pycharm's documentation of [Managing сode сoverage suites](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/switching-between-code-coverage-suites.html?_ga=2.146148663.2048538381.1585839923-165121590.1584736651) there should be a way to

> "Upload... a coverage suite."

The directions say in order to do that you can

> "Click the Add button and select the necessary `.es` file in the dialog that opens."

What type of format is the `.es` file? Can `coverage.py` export into that format directly? Or does that have something to do with "build servers"? I couldn't find anything on google related to `.es` files + `coverage.py` and the only relevant result from searching PyCharm documentation for `.es` is the "Managing code coverage suites" page itself.

I tried importing the json report and the xml report produced by `coverage.py` but PyCharm wouldn't allow me to select it (or even show it and the "Add Suite" dialogue box).

What else can I try in order to import my `coverage.py` results into PyCharm?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No idea where `.es` comes from, `xml` works fine for me in PyCharm 2019.3.4 on macOS. Ticket to change the documentation https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41469

Comment: @PavelKarateev
Ahh thanks! When I tried importing the ```xml``` the file extension was ```.txt```. I changed it to ```.xml``` and the file was available for selection.
Now I have another error:  ```Test framework quit unexpectedly``` and the IDE logs show ```ions.AbstractImportTestsAction - Failed to detect test framework in {path_to_my_testing_directory}/testing/docker/coverage_results.xml; use no properties ```

Maybe it's the difference in paths between the running machine and my machine. But after some experimentation with absolute and relative paths I haven't had success at fixing it.

Comment: After reading a bit of the PyCharm source code https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/smRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/sm/runner/history/actions/AbstractImportTestsAction.java#L84-L88

It seems I need a config node in the XML. I exported a test suite run using the GUI of pycharm and copied the config node from the outputted xml into my coverage xml result and I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Never saw such an error before, would you mind creating a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker and attach your xml report? The ticket visibility level can be limited to you + JetBrains staff only.

Comment: @PavelKarateev done.  Link to the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41494

Answer (score 2):

I've been stuck with a similar issue for the past couple of hours, and finally got it working just now.

In my case, I was trying to get code coverage reports generated inside a docker container to be displayed on my PyCharm editor. Personally I was using `pytest` & `pytest-cov` to generate the report, which behind the scenes uses coverage.py, just like PyCharm does.

I faced the same issue to begin with; importing the produced coverage.xml would simply display everything as 0% covered. After managing to produce a working coverage report by running the project via PyCharm's integrated test runner tools, I was able to track down the difference between the two generated code coverage reports.

It turns out, you need **TWO FILES** for the code coverage report: The SQLite database generated by coverage.py which contains all the coverage information, as well as the XML formatted coverage report. These both also need to have the same filename, care for the extension.

Example working files

- coverage.coverage
- coverage.xml

Obviously, coverage.xml should contain the same coverage data as the sqlite db. You will have to open the SQLite database with pycharm, not the XML report. If you open the XML report, it will not work. If you don't have the XML report next to the SQLite database, you will get an error.

**My test command:**

```
pytest . --cov --cov-report xml
```

**My .coveragerc:**

```
[run]
branch = True
data_file = coverage.coverage
```

With the above pytest configuration, you should get `coverage.coverage` and `coverage.xml` as output files. Selecting the `coverage.coverage` file in the **Run > Show Coverage Data** dialog should get you a working coverage output.

Note that the `--cov` and `--cov-report` options are from the `pytest-cov` python package

Tested with the following PyCharm version:

```
PyCharm 2021.1.2 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-211.7442.45, built on June 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.57 amd64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 24
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.andrey4623.rainbowcsv (2.0), net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (2.17.0), org.jetbrains.plugins.go-template (211.6693.44), name.kropp.intellij.makefile (211.6693.108), com.intellij.kubernetes (211.7442.27), org.toml.lang (0.2.149.3939-211), com.deadlock.scsyntax (211.6693.111), intellij.prettierJS (211.7142.13), org.jetbrains.plugins.vue (211.7142.13), com.intellij.lang.jsgraphql (2.9.1), com.koxudaxi.pydantic (0.3.3), com.leinardi.pycharm.mypy (0.11.2), org.rust.lang (0.4.149.3939-211), org.intellij.plugins.hcl (0.7.10)
```